# Как удалить объект класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, я создаю объект некого класса:

sania=Chelovek()

Как удалить этот объект?

Comment: Попробуйте так `sania = None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя ключевое слово `del`:

```
del sania
```